# Java keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, keystore

To make a SSL connection with some server, whenever i run following command, followed by key-store default password "**changeit**" in windows to import the certificate in java keystore, following error occurred:

**COMMAND :**

```
keytool -import -file "E:\postgrescert\server.crt" -keypass changeit -keystore "C:\Java\JDK\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias pgssslninet
```

**ERROR:**

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

The **server.crt** is having below content:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            a1:ea:8c:61:61:0a:7d:69
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=CA, L=fg, O=XYZ, OU=IT, CN=Common Name/emailAddress=xyz.some@org.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 14 23:59:25 2013 GMT
            Not After : Jul 14 23:59:25 2013 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, L=fg, O=XYZ, OU=IT, CN=Common Name/emailAddress=xyz.some@org.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:de:7c:dd:6e:5f:98:85:52:b4:13:45:2d:69:26:
                    61:6c:d7:ad:d6:12:27:bf:e1:07:53:a4:76:27:29:
                    ca:3d:82:e5:63:8c:9e:a5:b0:24:f6:77:86:92:ab:
                    42:e5:26:8a:4a:ea:ea:4a:65:20:a1:3b:05:c7:e0:
                    31:8e:4c:6e:e5:9e:e4:9c:de:05:02:b3:59:70:00:
                    df:fb:b9:62:e1:5b:8e:1b:29:2d:7c:41:86:41:a9:
                    9e:24:f8:65:54:8c:cf:44:c4:7b:fa:12:b4:84:d1:
                    d7:d7:2f:14:32:f9:2e:7b:c2:d8:0b:35:c9:f5:8b:
                    64:ed:cf:84:6e:bf:97:d0:44:7b:6b:67:c6:5b:6f:
                    92:5d:f6:d7:01:b6:ba:96:37:c8:3b:f8:be:01:b5:
                    02:d1:6b:21:67:83:c8:fd:37:bd:70:e5:c1:e4:81:
                    b0:42:a9:04:b1:3d:33:4c:43:2b:33:cc:50:65:1e:
                    c0:15:8d:e3:5f:b0:9c:d9:04:09:18:e7:8f:80:56:
                    6f:45:1d:0a:c2:2d:02:7e:67:2a:8a:1b:73:4a:db:
                    80:e0:52:d6:33:23:c7:aa:48:b0:5c:ad:7f:8c:96:
                    7c:d4:84:61:4d:ae:d3:9c:ef:59:c1:bd:71:83:c3:
                    5e:a4:04:84:8f:cd:76:82:3a:86:43:ab:c1:f4:e9:
                    02:d5
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                C1:4F:FA:2E:8F:F3:36:FE:AE:9B:12:73:C7:08:C9:59:96:53:71:A7
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:C1:4F:FA:2E:8F:F3:36:FE:AE:9B:12:73:C7:08:C9:59:96:53:71:A7

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        6b:2f:5f:33:f8:bb:55:66:c3:48:c9:ae:64:c1:89:5b:e1:54:
        9a:bc:ae:34:87:7e:bc:e7:30:26:9e:65:58:42:79:19:e2:ee:
        93:2a:c7:2d:a9:45:b4:1c:7b:5f:5a:ec:12:e3:76:38:c5:44:
        aa:7f:bd:60:b6:a6:83:90:68:9d:8f:1c:7a:69:4a:58:a8:55:
        5a:36:9e:e3:69:76:50:0e:4c:30:54:11:4c:de:10:91:6f:aa:
        49:34:19:1c:96:cb:8a:6c:fd:df:19:ed:e1:84:2b:05:12:68:
        e6:af:c5:59:c2:61:ca:10:2c:8e:cc:0a:34:7e:08:e5:22:ac:
        01:fd:fc:4d:16:4f:66:29:58:ac:8e:25:79:3d:de:b6:ef:55:
        6e:26:c5:75:9d:6d:57:4e:02:89:b8:c1:b8:47:b7:09:9b:07:
        cf:5b:a3:bc:a3:6b:ef:a1:4c:95:a0:be:0f:d4:63:fe:35:c6:
        c6:42:10:0b:28:13:02:a3:6e:b3:bf:ae:57:a8:bd:a1:25:6a:
        2d:cd:c7:20:64:4b:2e:f2:b2:c9:5c:85:cf:6f:de:39:86:84:
        94:d3:01:c5:25:b7:ec:65:1b:5f:93:ec:9d:cc:81:fa:c7:34:
        fc:e4:e2:5c:3f:4b:cc:83:bb:f0:67:88:1f:f6:a1:3b:9e:00:
        7b:ba:b2:79
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Can anyone help me to locate the exact issue behind this error.

**PS :** When i removed every thing above `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, it get successfully imported. Does the information above `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` is really required. Please help.

Regards,

Arun

Comment: Well explained by jww

My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889396/java-lang-exception-input-not-an-x-509-certificate-keytool-error/26639065#26639065

Comment: @jayeshVaghela - Thanks, but the data from `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` is already well formed and acceptable if i removed extra details(like Serial Number,Version etc) above `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to locate the exact issue behind this error.

`Keytool` can handle two formats. One is ASN.1/DER encoding, which looks like binary data under a hex editor. The other is RFC 1421, Certificate Encoding Standard, which is a Base64 encoding of the  certificate. See the docs on the [Keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html) at the Solaris site.

> When i removed every thing above `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, it get successfully imported. Does the information above `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` is really required.

The format you describe above is Internet RFC 1421 Certificate Encoding Standard. `Keytool` should be able to handle the format. The manual clearly states that format is allowed:

> Certificates are often stored using the printable encoding format
>   defined by the Internet RFC 1421 standard, instead of their binary
>   encoding. This certificate format, also known as "Base 64 encoding",
>   facilitates exporting certificates to other applications by email or
>   through some other mechanism.
>   ...
>
> Certificates read by the `-import` and `-printcert` commands can be in
>   either this format or binary encoded.

In the above, the "this format" is RFC 1421. The "binary encoded" is ASN.1/DER.

---

With that said, the certificate looks like a client certificate since it has a PKCS#9 email address in the `Common Name`, and it does not have a DNS name (like `example.com`). Yet is also has a `Basic Constraint` of `CA=TRUE`.

Placing email addresses and DNS names in the `Common Name` field is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/B Forums. Those names should be placed in `Subject Alternate Name` field. Use the `Common Name` for a friendly name or a display name like "John Doe" or "Datametrics".

Java also seems to follow the IETF standards closer than most others (others meaning tools and libraries; and not standards). But the RFCs tend to run fast and loose, and I don't recall the PKCS#9 email address/`CA=TRUE` flag being prohibited.

That issue may affect its import-ability. Bruno or EJP would probably know for certain.

Comment: Thanks. Would be great if you can also tell more about what the meta information above -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- exactly does and how can i exactly fix this error :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I just added an empty line at the end and keytool was happy.