# Is there a HTTPS Maven repository URL for spring source

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, osgi, maven-3

I need a HTTPS Maven repository URL for spring source to configure in my pom.xml:

Right now I use the following http urls:
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release
http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external

Comment: So what's the problem with current URL you got? I'm not entirely sure there's a valid use case of using https to pull maven artifacts. But if you insist you can setup your own Nexus mirror and run it over https

Comment: Well, we would like to pull the maven artifacts over a secure HTTPs connection. So I was on the lookout for HTTPs URL for spring but couldnt find any.

Comment: So you thing https is by definition secure? From a source in the internet ? Sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Same links like you used just use HTTPS:
https://repository.springsource.com/
https://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release
https://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external

*Added after the comment*

You should import the following 3 certificates in the trust store and to configure Java to use it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already but getting the following exception `java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching repository.springsource.com found` - When trying to build using `mvn clean install`.
I tried installing the certificates using Java `keystore` tool, after exporting certificates from firefox. It would be great if someone can shed light on this for me!

Comment: As I previously told I tried importing them to truststore, but failed with the above error. It would be helpful if you could let me know the proper steps, right from exporting through firefox and then keystore commands to do it properly.

Comment: [I found this answer!](http://www.coderanch.com/t/134384/Security/error-subject-alternative-names-secure) - But still I dont have a conclusive answer that works without writing any Java Code!!

Comment: Look here how to configure truststore in Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool an here how to import http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774722/using-httpclient-with-ssl-and-certificates/2774815#2774815

Answer (score 0):

Another option to improve security is that you always verify the [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) checksum after you have downloaded a dependency. [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) provides Spring artifacts for all released versions, as well as their corresponding SHA-1 checksums, e.g. [spring-core](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-core%7C3.2.3.RELEASE%7Cjar):

> spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.pom 230116bb23132569443ac0479c8ac7e33e9662e7
>
> spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar accdd65db57e79e49f2af037bb76f5a55a580f00

On Ubuntu, you can use the [sha1sum](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/sha1sum.1.html) command:

```
sha1sum spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

On Mac you can use the [openssl sha1](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1652) command:

```
openssl sha1 spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: if the data is compromised, couldn't you just compromise the checksum as well?